# c++ memory leak in StgStorage API

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, ole

I have following code to open OLE Storage from buffer. But it seem cause memory leak. It consume much memory when run. 
I dont know where it leak.

```
    int OleCompoundBase::LoadFile(BYTE* buffer, int buffer_len)
{
    dwOpenMode = STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE;  // open stream mode
    m_pRootStg = NULL;

    // Load from buffer
    ILockBytes *iLb = NULL;
    HRESULT hres =  CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &iLb);
    if (hres == S_OK) {
        ULARGE_INTEGER ui;
        ui.LowPart = 0;

        hres = iLb->WriteAt(ui, buffer, buffer_len, NULL);
        if (hres == S_OK) {
            hres = StgIsStorageILockBytes(iLb);
            if (hres == S_OK) {
                hres = StgOpenStorageOnILockBytes(iLb, NULL, STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_DENY_READ, NULL, 0, &m_pRootStg);
            }
        }
    }
    iLb->Release();

    return hres;
}
```

m_pRootStg is release in destructor

Comment: Have you tried passing `TRUE` as the second argument to [`CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378977(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: tried. it the same

Answer (score 0):

How are you measuring this leak? Just by looking at the numbers in Task Manager? Does the `m_pRootStg` object work correctly?

I don't know if I would call it a leak but since you are only setting `ui.LowPart` the other part might be non-zero and you could risk writing to a large offset. You should be using `ui.QuadPart = 0` if you want to write to the start of the buffer. If this is not causing you trouble then you are just getting lucky and the stack already has a 0 where the HighPart member is in memory.

Another problem is that you cannot call the LoadFile method more than once because you just throw away the old object (if any) with `m_pRootStg = NULL;` at the start of your code. If you are calling LoadFile multiple times you should change it to

```
if (m_pRootStg) 
{
  m_pRootStg->Release();
  m_pRootStg = NULL;
}
```